# Number of such five digit numbers formed of $0,1,2,3,4,5$ which are divisible by $6$ without repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I came across the question in the picture on the net. I couldn't figure
out the solution given. But what I got is total number of such $5$
digit numbers using the given digits will be $5.5!$. Half of them will
be divisible by $2$. And $1/3$ of them will be divisible by $3$. (Not sure though) What's next? I couldn't decipher what's written after that...

Please try to use the permutations and combinations approach if possible:

> A $5$-digit number is formed by using the digits $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$,
>   $4$ & $5$ without repetition. The probability that the number is
>   divisible by $6$ is:
>
> (A) $8\%$
>
> (B) $17\%$
>
> (C) $18\%$
>
> (D) $36\%$
>
> **Ans: (C)**
>
> **Hint**: Number should be divisible by $2$ and $3$.
>
> $n(S) = 5 \cdot 5!$; $n(A)$: reject '$0$' $= 2 \cdot 4!$
>
> reject '$3$' $= 4! + 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3!$
>
> Total $n(A) = 3 \cdot 4! + 6 \cdot 3! = 18 \cdot 3!$
>
> $\therefore p = \frac{18 \cdot 3!}{5 \cdot 5!} = 18\%$

Answer (score 3):

I. A number $n$ is divisible by $6$ if it is divisible by both $2$ and $3$.

II. A number $n$ is divisible by $2$ if the rightmost digit is even.

III. A number $n$ is divisible by $3$ if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$.

We have access to six digits, $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, which sum to $15$. We need a $5$-digit number. This means we must remove one digit such that the resulting digit-sum is divisible by $3$.

We can do this by either eliminating the $0$ (which results in the digit-sum $15$) or eliminating the $3$ (which results in the digit-sum $12$). This will allow us to create numbers that are divisible by $3$ no matter how we order the digits.

Your picture/solution is counting up the possible even numbers for both cases after the divisibility-by-$3$ rule has been satisfied by rejecting a particular digit from the set.

Answer (score 3):

We try to count how many five-digit numbers formed with digits $0,1,2,3,4,5$ are divisible by six.

To begin, we note three important facts:

- To be a five-digit number, the first digit must **not** be a zero (otherwise it would technically be a four-digit number.  $01234$ is a four digit number)
- To be divisible by six, the number must be divisible by two, so the final digit must be either $0,2,$ or $4$
- To be divisible by six, the number must be divisible by three, so the sum of the digits must add up to a multiple of three.  The only way for this to occur with the desired digits and no repetition of digits is if **exactly one of** $0$ or $3$ is used.  (*the proof of which follows from modular arithmetic*)

So, putting this information together, we start counting.

**Case 1:** $0$ is not used

- Pick the final digit: It can either be a two or a four.  - $2$ choices
- Pick how the rest of the digits are arranged.  - $4!$ choices

**Case 2a:** $3$ is not used and $0$ is at the end

- Pick how the rest of the digits are arranged.  - $4!$ choices

**Case 2b:** $3$ is not used and $0$ is *not* at the end

- Pick the final digit: It can be either a two or a four.  -$2$ choices
- Pick the location of the zero.  It cannot be at the start or the end.  $3$ choices
- Pick how the rest of the digits are arranged.  $3!$ choices

There are then a total of $2\cdot 4!+4!+2\cdot 3\cdot 3! = 108$ possible five-digit numbers satisfying the conditions.

The total number of five-digit numbers that can be created with those available digits will be $5\cdot 5!=600$.  (Arrange all six digits in a row, the final digit is unused.  Remove the "bad" arrangements where zero is the leading digit for $6!-5! = 5\cdot 5!$)

The probability that a five-digit number formed from those digits is divisible by six is then $\frac{108}{600}=0.18$

Comment: "_the proof of which follows from modular arithmetic)_" Could you provide me with any link on the net for the same? If this is not possible , kindly tell me how to approach the proof. I could not find anything available on the net for this

Comment: @Adhway suppose otherwise that both $0$ and $3$ are used.  That implies that the missing digit is one of $1,2,4,5$... call that number $x$... but in each case we have the total sum of digits equal to $0+1+2+3+4+5-x$ which simplifies as $15-x$ but this is never a multiple of $3$ when $x$ was itself not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @Adhway if your question is more about why the number being or not being a multiple of $3$ is related to whether or not its digits are a multiple of $3$... that surely already exists on this site and others many times, but the sketch of the proof is to recognize that the two digit number $\overline{ab} = 10a+b = 9a+a+b\equiv a+b\pmod{3}$ simply by the nature of how decimal numbers are represented.

Comment: Ohk thank youu!